# How can the axle have acceleration if it has no mass?

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the problem I am trying to solve the axles and string have no mass. My friend who solved it said I need to find the acceleration of the axle by taking the second derivative of the displacement of the axel with respect to the ceiling, but how can the axle have acceleration if it’s given that it has no mass. [image]

Comment: Which part in your diagram are you calling the "axel"? If it moves at a finite velocity, and that velocity changes, why don't you think you can call that an accelleration?

Answer (score 1):

In typical problems “massless” actually means “negligible mass”. It is a simplifying assumption that just says that the forces on the massless object always balance. It can still accelerate, but its acceleration must be determined by other constraints rather than by the forces which act on it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but what do you mean by other constraints?

Comment: For example, in this problem the length of the string is constant.

Comment: I get what your saying, but In this situation the pulley systems axle isn’t moving down, so how could it accelerate? And why do you take the derivative of the displacement with respect to the ceiling  to find acceleration when their is no time factor. For example if an object is a  specific distance from another object it could have displacement but where is the acceleration? You don’t have to answer the question but maybe you have any websites you could refer me to?

Comment: @Yaniv Arazi comments are intended only to improve the answer. They are not for discussion or for follow up questions. For that style of back and forth discussion I would recommend physicsforums.com

Answer (score 0):

The only axle evident in your diagram would be at the center of the pulley.  Since it is not translating it's mass would be relevant only if were rotating with the pulley.  Usually in pulley problems, it is specified that the axle exerts no frictional force.